# Batch file to remove paragraph if it contains certain words

Tags: batch-file

I need to delete a paragraph from a .txt file, but only if it includes the string 'Type: Certain'. There are two new lines, a '^**', and two more new lines between every paragraph. I've found lots of information on how to remove a line if it includes a certain word, but nothing about a paragraph.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please edit your question, and provide some code sample

Comment: Your question is off-topic (as you are just requesting code) and unclear (how do you define a "paragraph?). Please read the [tour] and learn [ask]!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this using [JREPL.BAT](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6044) if you are not afraid of regular expressions.

Your specs are a bit unclear. Based on my understanding of your layout, I assume only paragraphs 2, 6, and 8 should be preserved in the sample text below:

**test.txt**

```
This is paragraph 1 that should be deleted
xxxx Type: Certain xxxx
End of paragraph 1

^**

This is paragraph 2 that should be preserved
End of paragraph 2

^**

This is paragraph 3 Type:
Certain That should be deleted
End of paragraph 3

^**

This is paragraph 4
Type: Certain That should be deleted
End of paragraph 4

^**

Type: Certain

^**

This is paragrpah 6 that should be preserved
End of paragraph 6

^**

This is paragraph 7 that should be deleted
Type: Certain. End of paragraph 7

^**

This is paragraph 8 that should be preserved

^**

This is paragraph 9 that should be deleted
Type: Certain
```

**Here is a solution using JREPL.BAT**

The regex search for the paragraph delimiter and deletion trigger can be modified by changing the definitions of `p` and `d` respectively.

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "p=\r?\n\r?\n\^\*\*\r?\n\r?\n"  %= Paragraph delimiter =%
set "d=\bType:\s+Certain\b"         %= Text that indicates deletion =%

set "find=(%p%)?(?:[\s\S](?!%p%))*%d%[\s\S]*?(?:(%p%)|(?![\s\S]))"
set "repl=$txt=($1&&$2)?$1:''"

call jrepl find repl /m /v /jq /f test.txt /o -
```

**And here is the file after the paragraphs have been removed:**

```
This is paragraph 2 that should be preserved
End of paragraph 2

^**

This is paragrpah 6 that should be preserved
End of paragraph 6

^**

This is paragraph 8 that should be preserved
```

The possibility of `Type: Certain` in the first or last paragraph complicates the problem a bit.